# Does Elm have an equivalent of Haskell's "Read"

Tags: parsing, haskell, input, functional-programming, elm

I'm currently writing an online game where I use Haskell for the server-side backend and Elm for the frontend/rendering.

Right now I have my GameState as one big ADT, in a type simple enough that I can use it in Elm as well. I was hoping to avoid using JSON, and simply pass Elm the output of "show" on the data, which I could then parse-back into an ADT in Elm.

I'm wondering, is there anything equivalent to haskell's "read" which can automatically look at a string output by show, and parse it back into data? If not, are there any existing parser-libraries available for Elm?

If I do end up going with JSON, is there a way to automatically convert it into an ADT? (Something similar to Aeson's FromJSON, perhaps?)

Answer (score 4):

My understanding is that Elm—not having typeclasses—cannot easily have a *polymorphic* version of `read` or `fromJSON`. I also do not believe it has any good facilities for generic programming, so implementing something akin to `deriving` or OCaml's `with` would be difficult as well.

Unfortunately, this means your best bet is to write one-off functions for serializing and deserializing the various types you use. You could use aeson on the Haskell side and then write functions to/from JSON using [Elm's JSON library](https://github.com/evancz/Elm/blob/master/libraries/Json.elm).

Another option may be to try reusing the code produced by Haskell's `deriving Read` and porting it to Elm. However, this might be more work than it's worth, and I am not sure how to go about it, exactly.

Comment: This is exactly why I decided to wait for elm to mature more before using it seriously.

Comment: @johanatan what do you use for the frontend? JavaScript doesn't have type classes either.

Comment: @samboosalis: You can compile Haskell to JavaScript with Haste or GHCJS, both of which support typeclasses.

Comment: Yeah I took a look at http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/The_JavaScript_Problem.  obviously I'd love to run arbitrary Haskell in the browser. but how well does compiling Haskell to JavaScript work? can it compile Parsec? how big is the compiled JavaScript? how efficient is the compiled JavaScript? what bugs come up? can it interface with HTML/CSS/JS as well as Elm does, `port`s and `flow` and stuff? Are there any Haskell libraries that have a good model for UX, like Elm's Signals? I'm new to Elm (like a week) but I'm shocked at how easy it is to make (at least basic) web apps.

Comment: @samboosalis: Unfortunately, I haven't had the chance to use either, but my understanding is that they're both pretty complete. I've used a similar compiler for OCaml, and interfacing with JavaScript was never a problem. If you just want an easy way to create web interfaces backed by Haskell, you could also look at [threepenny gui](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Threepenny-gui). It runs a Haskell server instead of compiling to JavaScript, but it has a good model and is very nice for quick UIs.