# Elm try to convert string to option type

Tags: types, casting, elm

Is there any way in Elm to try and convert a string to an option type? Something a bit like...

```
conversionFunction : String -> MyOption
conversionFunction str = 
    case *SomeConvertionFunction* str of
        Nothing -> DefaulOption
        Just i  -> i

recievingFunction : List String -> List MyOption
recievingFunction list = 
    List.map (conversionFunction) list
```

I am trying to parse something from a URL, but I can see that happening a lot in the app I am building. I can also see why this might be difficult when data is attached, but quite useful for enumerations. I don't really want to have to write a case statement for all the strings in the enumeration by hand due mostly to laziness.

It seemed like it would be something in the core libraries, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is currently no Elm support for something like Haskell's `read` function or what could be described as reflection in other languages. In the current state of Elm, you'll need to write your own conversion function.

See [this related question from 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18542890/does-elm-have-an-equivalent-of-haskells-read).

Comment: Thanks for your speedy reply.