# How to find matching type by its string value in Elm

Tags: elm

If I have

```
type SomeType
= TypeA
| TypeB
| ...many more types
```

And I have a string that matches the type value (e.g., "TypeA"). How do I find a matching type?

```
stringToSomeType : String -> SomeType
stringToSomeType someType =
```

I could use case and just match each string with each type, but I bet there is a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no general way to achieve this in Elm. You'll have to use a case statement like you mentioned.

Such a general purpose function would be equivalent to Haskell's `Read` typeclass which provides ways to parse a string and convert it to data. Elm doesn't have typeclasses (yet), and there is no equivalent way to achieve this as of Elm 0.16.

There are a few related discussions on the matter:

- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/elm-discuss/sWqkLW7m61w
- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/elm-discuss/ED2MXQ6A4QY
- [Does Elm have an equivalent of Haskell's "Read"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18542890/does-elm-have-an-equivalent-of-haskells-read)